# Maven dependency issue with artifact - spring-boot-starter-test

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, spring-boot-test

There is a sub-dependency inside `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency versioned *2.3.3.RELEASE* which is `junit-vintage-engine`.

In my project's pom, when I add `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency, the test cases in my project are not executed but when I add the sub dependency which is present inside `spring-boot-starter-test` - `junit-vintage-engine` explicitly, then the test cases are executed properly when building the project.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please add your `pom.xml`.

Comment: First is the version 2.3.3.RELEASE of `spring-boot-start-test` which I suppose because `junit-vintage-engine` has a 5.6.2 as version instead. (https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.3.3.RELEASE/jar) furthermore the question is do you use junit or junit jupiter (aka JUnit 5) for testing? Do you use spring-boot-starter as your parent?

Comment: Yes, prefer JUnit Jupiter over the vintage one. Yes, keep the `spring-boot-start-test` dependency instead of managing JUnit versions on your own.